# What transactions will be included in the next block?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-selection

The miners decide whether a transaction will be included in the block.

What information do miners have about unconfirmed transactions?

How can I know, in detail, what transactions are going to be included in the block?

Comment: Willipm, I've attempted to clarify your question. If I've changed the intent of your question, feel free to use the 'rollback' feature. (It's under the revision history.)

Comment: I thought maybe the original question was asking about what details of transactions do miners see?

Comment: @Nick ODell  Chuck got me.Since George's answer has coverd both of the question,no bother to do the roll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what a miner sees at this very moment, provided that your wallet is synched, by calling `getrawmempool true` in your bitcoin console. What you'll get is broadcasted transactions not yet included in a block.

In short, miners scan this list and then allow the valid transactions with a higher fee to be included first in the block they are about to mine.

Comment: I called "getrawmempool true" but got "Returns all transaction ids in memory pool. (code -1)" as result.Did I miss something?

Comment: The command is `bitcoin-cli getrawmempool true`. `Code -1` is [RPC_MISC_ERROR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcprotocol.h#L45).